# Is there a way for Vim to define keywords defined by regular expressions?

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to have Vim treat as keywords strings that match:

```
( "(" <scope> ")" [:_/] ){0,1} <name>
```

where:

```
<scope> = [@+-.] ( ":" <name> )*
<name>  = [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

A regex to describe this definition of a keyword might be something like:

```
\(([@_-.]\(:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)*)\){0,1}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Some concrete examples:

```
(@:a):f
(+:b:c)_v
(-)/p
n
```

Using Vim's set **iskeyword** does not appear to be able to handle regular expressions.

I've considered expressions such as:

```
let @/ =~ '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>
```

but <cword> doesn't seem up to this task as well.

The use case for this is keying in * to search for words matching the regex that are under the cursor.

I've also considered whether **\%#** might be part of the solution; however, that seems to require splitting the regex into pre- and post-parts.

Is there a way for Vim to define keywords with regular expressions for use in initiating searches under the cursor, then using **n** and **p** to find next and previous matches? Solutions do not necessarily need to involve **iskeyword**. I'm suspecting that using **@/** is part of the solution. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you noticed, you can't define a "keyword" with a regex pattern. Moreover, Vim doesn't have a `<cpattern>` for reusing the "pattern" under the cursor or even a `[:pattern:]` character class for matching "patterns".

In other words, you can perfectly do:

```
:let @/ = '<arbitrary regex pattern>'
```

but you can't do:

```
:let @/ = buildpatternfromstring()
```

This means that you have two hard problems in front of you:

1. Grab the *pattern* under the cursor (what makes a pattern? where does it start? where does it end?).
2. Turn it *manually* into a proper Vim pattern.

And no built-in low-level helper at your disposal.